# System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto. C#

Tags: c#

les comento estoy creado un sistema de condominio en C# con conexión a base de datos Sql Server, pero al momento de correr el programa y querer guardar los datos  me genera la excepción... Adjunto una imagen del problema.

Como podría resolverlo ?

De antemano muchas gracias por el apoyo, quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Saludos Cordiales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código como texto

Comment: y no coloques una parte del codigo, quizas el error esta donde no se ve.

Comment: Por lo visto el problema no es con tu conexion. La exception FormatException usualmente ocurre en tipos int, float,double, etc. y es porque los datos que pasaste no son solo numeros, es decir, no tienen el formato correcto. en donde tienes in.parse(...) y Convert.ToInt32(...), ahi se genera la exception, revisa que los datos que entras en esos campos sean solo numeros.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Alguna de las conversiones que estás realizando están arrojando un error de formato porque está recibiendo un valor que no se puede convertir, en este caso, a `Int32`. Podrías estar pasando un espacio en `TxtDpi.Text`, `TxtEdad.Text` o en `TxtNumero.Text`.

Para saber dónde está el error, te recomiendo realizar las conversiones antes de pasar los valores a tu constructor. Ej:

```
int dpi = Convert.ToInt32(TxtDpi.Text);
int edad = int.Parse(TxtEdad.Text);
int numero = int.Parse(TxtNumero.Text);

Inscripcion inscripcion = new Inscripcion(dpi, TxtNombre.Text, edad, TxtCorreo.Text, numero, ...);
```

También será muy útil si compartes el fragmento de código de la línea que arrojó la excepción como texto, en vez de como imagen.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu aporte, te comento que he realizado los cambios sugeridos pero aun genera el error  y el error ahora me lo tira en esta linea de codigo int dpi = int.Parse(TxtDpi.Text);

Comment: Mi sugerencia era para entender con exactitud dónde se generaba el error. Ahora que lo sabemos tienes que revisar el contenido de `TxtDpi.Text` en tiempo de ejecución, ya que trae un caracter que `System.Convert.ToInt32(String)` considera inválido.